# How to see details about errors after running DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-administration

I'm adding partitions to an existing table in an Oracle database by creating an intermediary table and then using DBMS_REDEFINITION api to copy dependents from the original table.

```
CREATE TABLE my_schema.interm_tb AS SELECT * FROM my_schema.original_tb WHERE 1 = 0;

-- add partitions on my_schema.interm_tb
```

When running the script bellow I am getting num_errors > 0. However, `select object_name, base_table_name, ddl_txt from DBA_REDEFINITION_ERRORS;` doesn't find any error details. How can I see the error details? I am running as SYS user if it matters.

```
DECLARE
         num_errors PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.start_redef_table('my_schema', 'original_tb', 'interm_tb');
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS('my_schema', 'original_tb', 'interm_tb',
                                                        DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_ORIG_PARAMS, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,
                                                        num_errors);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('num_errors=' || num_errors);
END;
```

*Edit 1:*
With ignore_errors set to false I get:

```
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01442: column to be modified to NOT NULL is already NOT NULL
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REDEFINITION", line 2304
```

So I tried to get all not null constraints on the intermediary table and drop them by adding this block before calling `DBMS_REDEFINITION.start_redef_table` - this fixed the errors:

```
FOR q IN (
                    select 'alter table "' || owner || '"."' || table_name || '" DROP CONSTRAINT "' || CONSTRAINT_NAME || '"' as sql_text
                    from dba_constraints where table_name='interm_tb'
                    )
                    LOOP
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(q.sql_text);
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q.sql_text;
                END LOOP;
```

Comment: What's the behaviour when `ignore_errors` flag is false?

Comment: I'm gettting `ORA-01442: column to be modified to NOT NULL is already NOT NULL`. I am creating the intermediary table as select from the original, if it makes any difference

Comment: Should have been more specific - is the error appearing in `DBA_REDEFINITION_ERRORS`? i.e. is the fact that you're ignoring errors causing you to not see them?

Comment: Thank you @Ben, in fact deleting the not null constraints on the intermediary table fixed the error.